# Handling Multiple API errors and display in screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch-api

I am calling two API requests, one to send location to server another to send user signup details to server.

If user signup details has duplicate phone number it will return 400 error and with message.

My requirement once user send successful location and user details, I have to capture error in user response for duplicate mobile number else it should continue to next page.

```
const first = () => {
    let value = {
      first_name: values.first_name,
      last_name: values.last_name,
      gender: values.gender,
      dob: values.dob ? new Date(values.dob).toISOString() : null,
      email: values.email,
      phone_number: values.phone_number,
    };

    let locationValues = {
      latitude: fetcedLocation?.latitude,
      longitude: fetcedLocation?.longitude,
      cur_status: "filled",
      // city: formik.values.dob,
      // state: formik.values.email,
    };

    requestInstance
      .post(API_ENDPOINT.LOCATION_REGISTRATION, locationValues)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data.status);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        toast.error(err);
        setLoading(false);
      });

    requestInstance
      .post(API_ENDPOINT.EMPLOYEE_FIRST_REG, value)
      .then((res) => {
        toast.success(res.data.message);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        toast.error(err);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  };
```

Here about is my request and if `EMPLOYEE_FIRST_REG` has any error I have to capture it and display in screen after they submit form again I have to sent response to server if they entered unique mobile number.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine.

If you want to show error message in `toast.error(err)` and if your response is bad request and carry message of error in message key.

you can simply show message through

```
toast.error(err.response.data.message)
```

Comment: Yes it works for first time fine, next time onwards it was contineously redirecting to next page and not giving error to halt